# How do I save the state of checkbox that is in a listview?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to know how I can save the sate of my checkbox? The checkbox is in a `listview` of birds. If you click the box it means you have seen that bird and saves the state. I have tried doing it with preferences but don't know if I am on the right track.

UPDATE

Here is the xaml for the BirdListZA

```
<Frame x:Name="frame" BackgroundColor="#f3f0e9" BorderColor="#f3f0e9" CornerRadius="20"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.95,0.9,0.9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <ListView x:Name="blistview" BackgroundColor ="#f3f0e9" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="blistview_ItemSelected" RowHeight="80"
                          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.95,0.9,0.9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
               
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    
                        <DataTemplate>
                        
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label  Text="{Binding BirdNames}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" TextColor="Black" Padding="20,20,0,0" BackgroundColor="#f3f0e9" FontFamily="appfontM"/>
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>

                        
                    </DataTemplate>

                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Frame>
```

This is the code behind for the BirdListAZ page

```
public partial class BirdListAZ : ContentPage
    {
        private ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel> listBirds;

        IEnumerable<birdlistmodel> GetBirds(string searchText = null)
        {
            var birds = new List<birdlistmodel>
            {
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 1, BirdNames = "Apalis, Bar-throated", isChecked = false }, 
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 2, BirdNames = "Apalis, Yellow-breasted", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 3, BirdNames = "Barbet, Acacia Pied", isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 4, BirdNames = "Barbet, Black-collared", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 5, BirdNames = "Batis, Cape", isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 6, BirdNames = "Batis, Chinspot", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 7, BirdNames = "Bee-eater, European", isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 8, BirdNames = "Bee-eater, White-fronted", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 9, BirdNames = "Bishop,Southern Red", isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 10, BirdNames = "Bokmakierie", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 11, BirdNames = "Boubou, Southern", isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 12, BirdNames = "Brownbul, Terrestrial", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 13, BirdNames = "Bulbul, Dark-capped",isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 14, BirdNames = "Bunting, Cape", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 15, BirdNames = "Bunting, Golden-breasted", isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 16, BirdNames = "Bushshrike, Gorgeous", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 17, BirdNames = "Bushshrike, Grey-headed", isChecked = false },
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 18, BirdNames = "Bushshrike, Olive", isChecked = false},
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 19, BirdNames = "Bushshrike, Orange-breasted", isChecked = false },
            };
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
                return birds;
            var lowerBirds = searchText.ToLower();
            return birds.Where(c => c.BirdNames.ToLower().StartsWith(lowerBirds));

            
        }
        

        public BirdListAZ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            blistview.ItemsSource = GetBirds(e.NewTextValue);
        }

        private void blistview_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((ListView)sender).SelectedItem == null)
                return;
            var birds = e.SelectedItem as birdlistmodel;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new BirdPages(birds.BirdNames, birds.BirdSelect));
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }

       async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

      async  private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new myBirdList());
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Preferences.Get("listbirds", "")))
            {

                var voels = GetBirds();
                listBirds = new ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>(voels);
                blistview.ItemsSource = listBirds;
            }
            else
            {
                string dataString = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("listbirds", "");

                ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel> listBirds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>>(dataString);
                blistview.ItemsSource = listBirds;
            }

        }
        private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
            var selectBird = checkbox.BindingContext as birdlistmodel;
            selectBird.isChecked = e.Value;           
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listBirds);
            Preferences.Set("listbirds", json);

        }

        
    }
}
```

The birdlistmodel page

```
class birdlistmodel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Voellist { get; set; }
        public string BirdNames { get; set; }
        public Button BirdSelect { get; set; }
        public bool isChecked { get; set; }
            
    }
```

Comment: if you have one checkbox per bird, then you will need more than one preference setting, or will need to store a list of values in the Preference setting.

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only save the checkbox's state by doing this, and it doesn't tell you which item is checked，and it's even messier if you have multiple choices.

If you want to display the selected status when you re-enter the page，you could add a `isChecked` property to your model.

Forexample:

the `birdlistmodel` class:

```
class birdlistmodel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Voellist { get; set; }
    public string BirdNames { get; set; }
    public Button BirdSelect { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
        
}
```

then in your xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="blistview" BackgroundColor ="#f3f0e9" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="blistview_ItemSelected" RowHeight="80"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.95,0.9,0.9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
           
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                
                    <DataTemplate>
                    
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label  Text="{Binding BirdNames}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" TextColor="Black" Padding="20,20,0,0" BackgroundColor="#f3f0e9" FontFamily="appfontM"/>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding isCheckd}" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>

                    
                </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

in your page.cs:

```
private void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        var selectBird = checkbox.BindingContext as birdlistmodel;
        selectBird.isCheckd = e.Value;
        //if you want save the data and checkbox state,you could save the data as a json string
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xxx);//xxx is the List<birdlistmodel> which you binding to the listview
        Preferences.Set("listbirds", json);
    }
```

and when you re-entry the page,you could get the data from the Preferences.

```
string dataString = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("listbirds","");
ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel> listBirds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>>(dataString);
```

the first time you entry the page,you should set all the `isChecked` property to `false`(because you don't have a choice).

```
var birds = new List<birdlistmodel>
        {
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 1, BirdNames = "Apalis, Bar-throated", isChecked = false}, 
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 2, BirdNames = "Apalis, Yellow-breasted", isChecked = false},
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 3, BirdNames = "Barbet, Acacia Pied", isChecked = false },
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 4, BirdNames = "Barbet, Black-collared", isChecked = false},
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 5, BirdNames = "Batis, Cape", isChecked = false },
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 6, BirdNames = "Batis, Chinspot", isChecked = false},
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 7, BirdNames = "Bee-eater, European", isChecked = false },
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 8, BirdNames = "Bee-eater, White-fronted", isChecked = false},
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 9, BirdNames = "Bishop,Southern Red", isChecked = false },
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 10, BirdNames = "Bokmakierie", isChecked = false},
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 11, BirdNames = "Boubou, Southern", isChecked = false },
            new birdlistmodel (){Id = 12, BirdNames = "Brownbul, Terrestrial", isChecked = false}
        }
```

when you check the checkbox the `checkbox_CheckedChanged` will be handle and change the states

**Update**：

```
private ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel> listBirds; //global variable
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("listbirds", "")))
        {
            var voels = GetBirds();
            listBirds = new ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>(voels);
            blistview.ItemsSource = listBirds;
        }
        else
        {
            string dataString = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("listbirds", "");

            listBirds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>>(dataString);
            blistview.ItemsSource = listBirds;
        }
       
    }
```

then in your

```
 private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        var selectBird = checkbox.BindingContext as birdlistmodel;
        selectBird.isChecked = e.Value;           
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listBirds);
        Preferences.Set("listbirds", json);

    }
```

Comment: OK i have made some changes still struggeling a bit. Look at my edit on original post.

Comment: @NicoBrits i have a update above,you should change and save the `isChecked` property in `checkbox_CheckedChanged`  method.You could check it.

Comment: How do I open `listbirds` when page is re-opened? Because when I close the page and open it again it just opens my original `GetBirds` which is the source of `List<birdlistmodel>`

Comment: When you re-opened the page,you could get the data from the `Preferences`,for example in the OnApearing method call `string dataString = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("listbirds","");
ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel> listBirds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>>(dataString);` here the listBirds is the listbirds  which you have saved before.

Comment: I did do that but what should i bind my `Listview` to then? Because at the moment is is binded to `GetBirds` which is my `IEnumerable` for the search. The `listBirds` is not used anywhere? And when i bind it to the `listBirds` when it is opened for the first time it will be blank.

Comment: I have updated my original post. By using your update everything works like it should. My only problem left i think now is the `isCheckedChanged`. I can't get the `listBirds` in the `Json` string. I have update it as well in my original post.

Comment: @NicoBrits You just need defined the listBirds  to a global variable in the page.See the update.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works on first deploy and the first change. Then when i open the list for the second time it works. But for the third time the `dataString` is null for some reason. It goes through the `if` to the `else` but then the list is `null`

Comment: @NicoBrits Since there is no complete project code, I don't know what's wrong with you, you could  try to make break point at where you call  `Preferences.Set("listbirds", json);`,see if the json is null or not

Comment: The `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listBirds)` is null when i start changing the second time. The `listBirds` to be exact.

Comment: @NicoBrits Could you get the listBirds correctly in onAppearing method ?If you could get it, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listBirds)`  should not be null

Comment: When i launch for first time the `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("listbirds", "")))` fires and the empty `listBirds` works. Then i change a checkbox, close the window and go in. The `else` then works and the listBirds is loaded. But then when i want to change again the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listBirds)` is null. And when i close the window again and open it the `if` is passed but in the `else` the `dataString` is null

Comment: It's weird,if you have passed into the `else`,it means `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("listbirds","");` is not null ,the `dataString` will not be null.

Comment: I know that is what is strange and i don't understand. Should i post complete code for you?

Comment: @NicoBrits Let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221986/1).

Comment: I can't. Not enough reputation :(

Comment: @NicoBrits You could edit your question and add the complete codes.

Comment: The issue is in your `else`,you should change `ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel> listBirds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>>(dataString);` to `listBirds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<birdlistmodel>>(dataString);`,you should use the global variable,otherwise listBirds will be null when you save to the  Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You will have more than one checkbox, just as you have more than one bird.
Use SQL Lite to create a simple database to store the checkbox state for each bird.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows